# How to use the ba command (Break on Access) in WinDbg?

Tags: bit-manipulation, windbg

I have a this very minimal C program:

```
#include <windows.h>

void funAdd() {
    int a = 2; // I want to break here
}

int CALLBACK
WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance,
    HINSTANCE PrevInstance,
    LPSTR CommandLine,
    int ShowCode)
{
    funAdd();
}
```

I would like to break inside the funAdd() function using break on access inside WinDbg. The visual studio dissassembly tells me that the `int a = 2` instruction is located at memory address `002416BC`:

[image]

According to the documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ba--break-on-access-

If I write the command `ba r4 02416be` I would expect the debugger to break inside my `funAdd()` function, however when I enter the command I get the following error: `Data breakpoint must be aligned`.

Am I understanding this correctly? And if so, how do I properly align this address to 4 bytes in order to match the `r4` command option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x2416be is instruction pointer or virtual address of the instruction

to set access breakpoint on this address you shouldn't use **r or w**  you should use **e**

**ba e 2416be**  this doesn't require either alignment or size

if you want to set a data breakpoint on your variable **a**

you have to **find the virtual address of a**

compilers normally align variable addresses so you normally don't have to worry about alignment

use **dv  /v  a**   ( you need private pdb for local variable display
and since windbg renamed the local var as a instead of ebp-xx you should be having your private pdb )

windbg will spit a result like 
**local var a @ xxxxxx**

here xxxxx is the address of variable a  ( 2 would be stored

in ths address  )

use **ba r4  or r2 or r1** as required on this address

be aware this address may be in stack   and this breakpoint may fire many times  before it actually hits your  condition

data read breakpoints are useful for global variables 
and are not  so good for locals and heap addresses that are dynamic in nature

you can specify arbitrary function address to dv to look at the functions locals (need private pdb )

```
0:000> dv /v /i /t /f funadd!funAdd
prv local  <virtual frame 2ffa84>-0x0004       int myvar
```

executing upto the function start

```
0:000> g funadd!funAdd
eax=767fed5a ebx=7ffd4000 ecx=00000000 edx=01351000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=01351010 esp=002ffeb8 ebp=002ffebc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
funadd!funAdd:
01351010 55              push    ebp
```

using local display

```
0:000> dv /V /i /t
prv local  002ffeb0          <virtual frame 2ffeb4>-0x0004       int myvar = 0n0
```

using display type command also will give the virtual address of the local

```
0:000> dt -n myvar
Local var @ 0x2ffeb0 Type int
0n0
```

you can set a read breakpoint on this address

```
0:000> ba r4 0x2ffeb0
```

execute and wait for you bp to hit

```
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=767fed5a ebx=7ffd4000 ecx=00000000 edx=01351000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=01351014 esp=002ffeb0 ebp=002ffeb4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
funadd!funAdd+0x4:
01351014 c745fc02000000  mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],2 <<<<<<<<<  ss:0023:002ffeb0=00000000
```

the value is not written yet to the local myvar

```
0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  002ffeb0 r 4 0001 (0001)  0:**** 


0:000> ? myvar
Evaluate expression: 3145392 = 002ffeb0

0:000> ? poi(myvar)
Evaluate expression: 0 = 00000000
```