# Who access a certain memory in windbg

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, windbg

How can I check on WinDbg which part of the code in an executable (disassembled) access a certain memory address?
For instance, (pseudo) "get_addresses_use 140000" -> 14853, 12435 (addresses on text section that access the address 140000).

Comment: Normally you'd set a watchpoint and run the program.  That will find code that accesses it via a pointer, which static analysis can't easily find.

Comment: A google search for "windbg breakpoint on memory write" turned up [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ba--break-on-access-) page for `ba (Break on Access)`: *The ba command sets a processor breakpoint (often called, less accurately, a data breakpoint). This breakpoint is triggered when the specified memory is accessed.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51221203/2189500 which already has a pretty detailed looking answer.

Answer (score 3):

Memory addresses are assigned to the program at runtime. For a disassembled program which does not run, no addresses have been allocated. Address 140000 may never be used at all.

Even if you run an executable that's hard to find out. Let's give an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data(1'000'000,00); // improper spacing can be fun
    int index;
    std::cin >> index;
    std::cout << data[index];
}
```

Given you know which address has been assigned to the vector, you can't tell which address will be accessed, because it depends on user input. If the user enters a negative number or a too large number, that's even undefined behavior.

You can however use a memory breakpoint [`ba`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/ba--break-on-access-) on an address. That way you can see whether a particular address is accessed right when it's accessed. For whatever I did so far, that was sufficient.

Comment: Terminology note: what you're describing for `ba` is what some other debuggers (such as GDB) call a "watchpoint".

Comment: @PeterCordes: thanks. I don't do Linux development, so I hardly have GDB knowledge. Maybe I should get into that. GDB seems more powerful and consistent when it comes to scripting.

Comment: I've never gotten into scripting GDB, myself.  If you were going to learn a new debugger, LLDB from LLVM is reportedly good.  I'd assume with the benefit of hindsight from GDB's successes and mistakes, they hopefully made good design choices.  Since I already know quite a few GDB commands, I haven't played with LLDB myself, either.